# UIButton title on 3 separate lines with SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton, multiline

I have been trying to code a UIButton with swift and I wanted to make the text on the button display over three lines. This is the code I have so far however it does not display over three lines and the size of the font doesn't work either. Not sure where I went wrong. Will really appreciate some advice!!

```
button.titleLabel!.text = "Line1 Line2 Line3"
button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 45)
button.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
button.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 3
button.titleLabel!.frame = CGRectMake(15, 54, 300, 500)
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `button.titleLabel!.text = "Line1\nLine2\nLine3"`

Comment: Using `\n` will give you a line break.

Comment: I can't seem to get the line break to work. I put that into the code but it still on the same line?